# Where can I get ISO lists for continent, country, and currency to use on my web pages?

Tags: standards, internationalization

I have done quite a bit of looking around, and found several lists based on the ISO standards, but of dubious quality, e.g. with null or blank entries, extra entries that are not real currencies etc.

Can somebody recommend a source that I can use for these lists? Does someone like Google API maybe offer these as a service? Where should I go looking for these?

I would like to get data in delimited file, xml, json, anything friendlier than EDIFACT basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd think the [International Standards Organisation](http://www.iso.org/iso/home.htm) would do this, but no, its, you guessed it **WIKIPEDIA**!

Why this should be the case is a mystery, but here you are. It even offers the lists in machine readable formats if you have a look around.

- [List of sovereign states and dependent territories by continent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_and_dependent_territories_by_continent_%28data_file%29)
- [Currencies to ISO 4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217)
- [Countries to ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1)

Comment: ISO provides them as well. And they provide the data in [more consumable formats (XLS, XML)](http://www.currency-iso.org/iso_index/iso_tables/iso_tables_a1.htm) and for country codes: [XML, TXT (semicolon-separated), and HTML](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_3166_code_lists). I suppose they could offer a REST web service that lets you access it in any data format you want (XML/JSON/CSV/HTML) and guarantees the latest revision.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté brilliant, I had no idea. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I'm being too fussy, but I think it's something of a design shortcoming that it's so much easier for a person to read these tables on wikipedia that to get machine readable data. I would put a download link above each table. Will suggest it on the wiki as well. I mean, they have raw data, put effort into presenting it, only so readers have to put effort into consuming it.

Comment: @ProfK no I don't think you're being fussy, the Wiki UI sucks, especially when editing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best resource I've found for country information:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/country-codes/master/data/country-codes.csv